# Mongodb backup and restore: error reading database not authorized to execute command

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, database-restore

Apologise for my maybe trivial question, but I'm new to Mongodb.

I have successfully dumped a mongodb database, say `DB_A` which has a default user, `user_A` with role `dbOwner`.
I'm trying to import the dump, into another database, `DB_B` which has a default user, `user_B` with role `dbOwner, dbAdmin`.

So, destination database has different name and different user, but same `SCHEMA`.

When I try to restore, what I got is: `error reading database not authorized on DB_A to execute command: { listCollections: 1, cursor: {batchSize: 0} }`

It sounds to me like `user_B` is trying to access (listCollections) `DB_A` but doesn't have rights.

Note
The export is a MLab dump that consists of:

> - admin folder [system users, system version, BSON and JSON files]
> - DB_A foder [containing BSON and JSON files]
> - oplog.bson file

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing, you are trying to connect to DB_A. So either you didn't restore into DB_B correctly, or your connection string is wrong.

Comment: Alex, my connection string is right, I am able to connect to DB_B and look at the collections.